# JQuery DropDown plugin

Tags: jquery

I just found a JQuery plugin for DropDown, but I am not following how to use it. It's documentation is also not available.

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryselectcombo/

Is there any other similar free plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice one

[jquery.combobox](http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/page/jquerycombobox.aspx)

[Stylish Select 0.3](http://www.scottdarby.com/plugins/stylish-select/0.3/)

and also [jQuery selectbox replacement](http://www.brainfault.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-selectbox-replacement/)

Comment: all three links are dead

Answer (score 3):

It's documentation can be found inside the .js file. As the example demo page says:

> Please see source of js file for information on how to use this plugin.